# Central Limit Theorem in Minitab 15

Tags: math-software

I have a assignment for Minitab 15, which about varoius statistics concepts (basic and foundamental topics) but have a big problem with understanding of of questions! Also I do not know how it's possible to use Minitab® to answer this question, I would be glad some one get me clue. (- I don't need some one to solve the problem just help to how could do it in Minitab®)

This is the question:

> Generate 15 000 samples of size
>   n = 15 each, from the Poisson
>   distribution with parameter λ=3
>   Calculate the mean from each sample.
>   You have now 15 000 means. 
>   
>   Draw a histogram of these 15
>   000 means. What is the shape of the
>   histogram? Calculate the mean of the
>   15 000 means and the standard
>   deviation. Use the Central Limit
>   Theorem to explain why they should be
>   close to 3 and 0.4472 respectively.
>   Also explain the shape of the
>   histogram.

Also as I'm new to statistics, can't understand how it's possible to have 1500 means?

Comment: You have 15,000 samples, which you can think of as different trials. So if you calculate the mean of each trial, you have 15,000 of them.

Comment: are you having problems with the math or the computer?  go to office hours.

Comment: Actually non of them, and both of them, I have problem with Math in Minitab® ;) I don't know how to generate Poisson random samples with 1500 sample of size n=15, I think of :
<pre> MTB > Random 15000 C1-C15;
SUBC> Poisson 3.
MTB >
</pre> But don't seems corect!!

Comment: This doesn't seem to belong here.  Voting to close as off-topic

Answer (score 1):

Use the drop-down menu in Minitab, not the command line.

Place the 15000 samples of size 15 each in 15 columns. This can be done with 
Calc > Random Data > Poisson. 
It will take a few seconds. Now there are 15000 rows and 15 columns of data.

Next compute the means of each of these 15000 rows and place them in a new column. This can be done with 
Calc > Row Statistics.

Finally make a histogram of this column.